# UserControl with Dependency Property inside an ItemsControl: how to Bind element of ItemSource to x:Name of UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, itemscontrol, caliburn.micro

My class IFrame can contain other IFrames:

```
public interface IFrame
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Summary { get; }

    BindableCollection<IFrame> SubFrames { get; set; }
}
```

To present an IFrame, I have a custom UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.FrameView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="FrameXName">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=FrameXName, Path=Id}" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

With codebehind:

```
public partial class FrameView : UserControl
{
    public FrameView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty IdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Id", typeof(int), typeof(FrameView));

    public int Id
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And thus I can display a Frame in a FooView.xaml using:
   `<Views:FrameView x:Name="Frame1" Width="50" Height="50"/>` IF I define the following in FooViewModel.cs:
   `public IFrame Frame1 { get { return Frames.ElementAt(1); } }`

**My Goal:**

I want to have a FrameView displayed for every IFrame in a collection, for example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Views:FrameView x:Name="{Binding}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where `public BindableCollection<IFrame> Frames` is defined.

Unfortunately, this does not work, the compiler says `MarkupExtensions are not allowed for Uid or Name property values, so '{Binding}' is not valid.`

How can I achieve my goal? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have answered my own question but can only officially answer it within 8 hours. Until then:

So it appears, I had UserControl XAML tag all wrong as far as the Dependency Property goes.

If I use `Id="{Binding Path=Id}"` instead of `x:Name=""` and remove `x:Name="FrameXName"` from my UserControl definition everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your datatemplate you can replace

```
<Views:FrameView x:Name="{Binding}" Width="50" Height="50" />
```

with

```
<Views:FrameView Id="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="50" Height="50" />
```

should work fine